# Loader with Javascript in Flask WTForms

Tags: javascript, flask, flask-wtforms

I am attempting to include a loading icon with Javascript in my Flask App that uses WTForms. I have the loader set up as an `onclick` event that sets the loader to being shown upon button click. The problem is, it shows the loader upon click even if the Form is not validated (I.E. has nothing in it).

Normally I would just check the form like:

HTML:

```
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-info" name="submit_button" value="Retrieve Data" onclick="test1()">
<div id='loader' class="loader"></div>
```

JS:

```
window.onload = function () {

         document.getElementById("loader").style.display = "none";
}
function test1() {
var user_input = document.getElementById('form').value;
if (user_input) {
    document.getElementById("loader").style.display = "block";
}
}
```

How can I check the value of a WTForm using Javascript, WITHOUT resorting to waiting for the data to come all the way through the Flask API (no point in having a loader if it only shows up as the data comes through anyway)?

This is my WTForms code:

```
<div class="form-group">
{{ form.service.label(class="form-control-label") }} {% if form.service.errors %} {{ 
form.service(class="form-control form-control-lg
is-invalid")}}
<div class="invalid-feedback">
{% for errors in form.service.errors %}
<span>{{ error }}</span>
{% endfor %}
</div>
{% else %} {{ form.service(class="form-control form-control-lg") }} {% endif %}
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as i understand it, you're trying to check if there is a value in an input field, which is inside a form.

I interpret this line:

```
document.getElementById('form').value;
```

like you give it the id of the form and not the input field you are checking. And you can't do that because, it will always return false.

What you instead need to do is get the value from the specific input field, and not the whole form.

That means inserting the id of the input field you are checking, into the `document.getElementById('insert input field id');`

Comment: Yes, you are correct. But how do I attach an id to the Flask Form such that it could be read by the `document.getElementById`. My code is above and you can see how because it is rendered by Jinja, I can't as easily ad an id... or can I?

Comment: @find_all in your case, the id of the form is `service` because the form fields is called `service`

Comment: Ok, this worked somewhat. I'm going to give you an upvote for that. But I am still not getting the value, just an empty object. I thought I could bypass this by using typeof in my conditional (I.E. Null vs String for example) but when I use this I just get an empty object, whether there is a string in the field or nothing at all. Will be happy to accept your answer if we can figure out how to get it to work for a conditional.

Comment: Ok, figured it out by using `.value` and testing for string lengths. Going to accept your answer.